# explaining a macro that use bitwise operator

Tags: c

what is the use for that macro when it is used, I know how to set a bit, clear a bit, but that macro I can't not understand it

```
#define nbit(a,b)(!((a) & (b)))
```

Comment: What's the problem? Instead of writing that (possibly difficult) `and`ing stuff, just use the macro. When to use it? When you wanna bit-and two values and make sure the result is zero

Comment: returns true when bit N of A and B are not both 1, for any N in the range of valid bit size of A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((a) & (b))` has bits 1 where both a and b have 1, 0 otherwise. ! is negation, that is, the expression is true if there are no common 1 (set) bits, false otherwise.

Comment: Ok, I didn't explain clearly enough: common 1 bits. I'll edit.